# PHP: simplexlsx Parser specialchars

Tags: php, parsing, utf-8, xlsx, htmlspecialchars

hope someone can help me out.

Im using simplexlsx 
( http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6279-PHP-Parse-and-retrieve-data-from-Excel-XLS-files.html ) to read out my Excel files and display them/write them into my DB.

Now i have the problem that the class wont parse specialchars like : "Ä, Ü, Ö, ß..." correct
i tryed to write a function to fix it, but it wont work.

Hope some of you guys could help me.

Thx so far
xQp

// Try

```
function unhtmlspecialchars( $string ){    
  $string = str_replace ( '&amp;', '&', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&#039;', '\'', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&quot;', '"', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&lt;', '<', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&gt;', '>', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&uuml;', 'ü', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&Uuml;', 'Ü', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&auml;', 'ä', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&Auml;', 'Ä', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&ouml;', 'ö', $string );    
  $string = str_replace ( '&Ouml;', 'Ö', $string );  
  return $string;
}
```

tryed to get call that function within the simplexlsx.class before return the $value

// edit 2
my try was the to add the function unhtmlspecialchars to simplexlsx.class and call it at the end of the "function value()" before returning the value 
like this just to test it...

```
  $value2 = $this->unhtmlspecialchars($value);

        return $value2 ;
```

Comment: can you post your tries? :)

Comment: Is the page where you're displaying these set to utf-8?

Comment: posted and yes it is set to utf-8
if i try to write a special char out of the display function it works just within the table display, so it must be somewhere at the parsing part

Comment: What does "not correct" mean exactly? What does it look like?

Comment: excample:
should display "grün" but shows "grÃ¼n"

Comment: nevermind guys i got it... 
sometimes its just as easy as you never thought
just doing 
$value = utf8_decode($value); <-- this part
return $value; but thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solution (as stated by the OP in the comments) is to use

```
utf8_decode($value);
```

to restore the special chars in the output.